# For a particular method, how can I view the checked exceptions in java using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, methods, exception, jvm

For a particular method, how can I view the checked exceptions in java using reflection? There does not seem to be support for this in the JDK.

Comment: Note: You can only get the declared exceptions. You can declare a high level Exception e.g. IOException when only a few subclasses might be thrown (or none) You can declare RuntimeExceptions+Errors and they will appear also. There are also tricks to throw undeclared check exceptions (best avoided)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method in `Method`:

`public Type[] getGenericExceptionTypes()`

Then you have to iterate through the types if you want to separate checked and unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Also, public Class<?> getExceptionTypes() returns the actual classes.